# Getting MD5 hasmap for comparison

Tags: import, karate

i am trying to get the MD5 hash for a string using karate for comparison.

i have created a common.feature with below content:

- **Feature**: common methods for using across
- **Background**:

  ```
  def getMDhash = function(pdfFile){return DigestUtils.md5Hex(pdfFile).toUpperCase()}
  ```
- **Scenario**: sample, using another feature file to call it:

  - **Feature**: Compute All
- **Scenario**: trial and error

  ```
  call read('common.feature')
  def final = getMDhash('my first attempt')
  print final
  ```

I have added :

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.*;
```

in *test.java file.

However, i am still getting this error while execution:

> Scenario: trial and error  Time elapsed: 0.019 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: getMDhash('my first attempt')
>           at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.eval(ScriptBindings.java:115)
>           at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.updateBindingsAndEval(ScriptBindings.java:103)
>           at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.evalInNashorn(ScriptBindings.java:88)
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalJsExpression(Script.java:362)
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:284)
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:170)
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:598)
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:524)
>           at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.def(StepDefs.java:305)
>           at ?.* def final = getMDhash('my first attempt')(testSuite/users/dummy.feature:7)
>   **Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "DigestUtils" is not defined in  at line number 1**
>           at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
>           at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454)
>           at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
>           at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
>           at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
>           at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
>           at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.eval(ScriptBindings.java:108)
>           at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.updateBindingsAndEval(ScriptBindings.java:103)
>           at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.evalInNashorn(ScriptBindings.java:88)
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalJsExpression(Script.java:362)
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:284)
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:170)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing the load of `DigestUtils`. Try:

```
* def getMDhash = function(pdfFile){ var DigestUtils = Java.type('replace.me.DigestUtils'); return DigestUtils.md5Hex(pdfFile).toUpperCase(); }
```

Please refer to this section of the docs for a similar example: https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-basic-authentication-example